# How can I use Microsoft.Web.Administrator to get sites by Port number

Tags: c#-4.0, iis-7, iis-8, servermanager

I've an application that remotely stops/restarts app pools/sites and checks the status of the app pools/sites as well. At present these are managed using the DirectoryEntry class e.g.

```
private DirectoryEntry FindSite(int nPort)
{
    using (var sites = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format(m_adSitesPath,m_RemoteServerName)))
    {
        sites.RefreshCache();

        foreach (DirectoryEntry de in sites.Children)
        {
            de.RefreshCache();
            if (de.SchemaClassName == "IIsWebServer")
            {
                string port = GetNullableDirMultiValuePart(de, "ServerBindings", 0, 1);
                if (nPort == int.Parse(port))
                {
                    return de;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

this method is failing on any servers running IIS 8, on another question it was suggested I should start looking at using the Microsoft.Web.Administrator classes. Could someone please point me in the right direction so I get a list of sites by Port using the Microsoft.Web.Administrator namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sample code is as below,

```
private List<Site> FindSite(int nPort)
{
    var result = new List<Site>();
    var server = new ServerManager();
    foreach (Site site in server.Sites)
    {
        foreach (Binding binding in site.Bindings)
        {
            if (binding.EndPoint.Port == port)
            {
                result.Add(site);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

where MWA defines strong types (`Site`, `Binding`, and so on) instead of `DirectoryEntry` which does not correspond to a meaningful type.

You can find the class reference here,

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration(v=vs.90).aspx